# What is the right design for two objects that share a dependency on another object?

Tags: ruby, oop

I've been struggling with a design problem for a bit.  I have an object Foo with an array of objects Bar.  There are a series of calculation methods that are completely coupled to Foo, and depend on full knowledge of the array of Bar.  So should I:

- make a Calculator class and pass in the array of Bar objects.  This seems bad to me because I can't test Calculator as a stand-alone unit, since Foo and Calculator both depend on the same array of Bar.
- make a Calculator module and somehow extend Foo so that it includes Calculator?  I haven't been able to figure out a good way to do that, where Calculator automatically has all of the knowledge of Foo that it needs.  Is this possible?
- just keep Calculator in Foo since it is so coupled to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your architecture should not depend on object class but on interfaces.

The instance of `Foo` should in constructor require a parameter which implements interface `iCalculator`. And you method `addBar` should only require that you pass in to it something that implements `iBar` interface. And Calculator object ( which was passed to `Foo` ) should be able to perform `calculate` method on any instance of `iBar` object.

Now you can test all three object in isolation , if you provide Mocks with same interfaces.

The 'solution' actually is just application of [Dependency inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) which is one of the which is one of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles/

Comment: Here is a video, explaining this principle : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvFK_BXv3P4

Comment: "The instance of `Foo` should in constructor require a parameter which implements interface `iCalculator`" - in Ruby, would `iCalculator` be a class or module?

Comment: @Andrew-Grimm afaik, ruby doesn't really have interfaces, but closest that you have are modules. But i guess, you **can** use specific class, just it will be more of an effort.